# Jointly owned inherited house

Tags: united-states, real-estate

My brother and I own an inherited house, his son and family has been living there rent-free for 7 years.  Brother has been paying the taxes ($12k) and homeowners insurance, and what maintenance has been done.  I want to sell, he does not.  If it comes to a partition sale, can I claim the 7 years of back rent to off-set what he has paid so we can split the proceeds in half.  I would like for them to buy my half but that does not seem likely.

Comment: Is your  brother living in the house with his son and family? Or is it your brother's son and the son's family that is living there?

Answer (score 4):

This is a potentially legal question. 
"Can I claim?" - It's a bit late in the game. We're not here to reprimand people for what's past, but to try to offer a solution for now.

You need to go to him and get to the point. You own half of a $600K (am I close?) home and are seeing no return on your equity. You'd like to sell it and get your half, at minimum, but feel that you are entitled to a bit of the lost rent. Half, right? And offset by half the taxes he paid. If the house rents for $2000, you should have seen $12K/yr, less $6K for tax. Or only $6,000/yr. But that adds up over time. And it's only 2% on your locked up $300K.

He can say no. You might have to go to court to force a sale. The court might give you something for the 7 years, or not, it depends on the judge.

For anyone who reads this on inheriting such a house as joint owners, nail the details down at the time you inherit. Else resentment can build up, and things can get ugly.

Comment: It's apprx $80k small 1944 house their parents lived in.  Your last paragraph is spot on - resentment building up and will probably get nasty.  Never would have thought it would turn into 7 years of free rent to nephew, his children and his live-in girlfriend.

Comment: Highly recommend the book "Getting to Yes" for situations like this. Goal is to get to a fair resolution for everyone without getting nasty. Since you can force a partition sale, it's in his interest to work it out, too. Keep mom and dad in mind, they left you the house hoping you'd work it out, right?

Comment: Did you mean $80k or $800k?

Comment: Was the $12K tax per year, or over the 7 years? The emotions don't change, but the numbers do. $80K house isn't quite the same as the $600K house I estimated.

Comment: House is just $80,000, taxes were $12K over the 7 years.  It's never seemed like enough money to fight over until now when I would like to make some improvements to my home as I get older - walk-in shower instead of tub, paying for maintenance for things I can't do myself anymore, etc.